# deleting the value of bin in a record of aerospike db which is of map type

Tags: aerospike, aql

say aerospike database is having recorded data like below :

name age characteristics
sachin 25 MAP('{"weight":70, "height":25}')

i want to remove "height":25 from MAP record via aql. How can i do that

Comment: Just wanted to comment AQL is a CLI, not a query language. It's built on the C client, so in the end those commands are translated to regular calls made by the C client. If you're developing an application you should use the clients for C, Java, C#, Go, Python, Node.js, etc

Answer (score 2):

```
aql> insert into test.demo (pk, name, age) values ("s", "sachin", 25)
aql> operate map_put(props, "height", 25) on test.demo where pk="s"
aql> operate map_put(props, "weight", 70) on test.demo where pk="s"
aql> set output json
OUTPUT = JSON
aql> select * from test.demo where pk="s"

[
    [
        {
          "name": "sachin",
          "age": 25,
          "props": {
            "height": 25,
            "weight": 70
          }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
          "Status": 0
        }
    ]
]

aql> operate map_remove_by_key(props, "height") on test.demo where pk="s"

[
    [
        {
          "props": [
            "height",
            25
          ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
          "Status": 0
        }
    ]
]

aql> select * from test.demo where pk="s"

[
    [
        {
          "name": "sachin",
          "age": 25,
          "props": {
            "weight": 70
          }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
          "Status": 0
        }
    ]
]
```